# Convert mod_rewrite Apache to Nginx?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm newbie on internet programming. I want to switch Apache to Nginx web server but still problem on Nginx mode rewrite.

My website location on `/home/user/public_html/read/` and my previous `.htaccess` file on `/home/user/public_html/read/.htaccess` like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mangas/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ - [F,L] 
RewriteRule ^mangas/([^/]+)/$ - [F,L] 
RewriteRule ^mangas(/?)$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2&page=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/?)$ index.php?manga=$1 [L]
```

How can I convert this mod_rewrite to nginx? (I'm soory because my english spell is not perfect)

Answer (score 1):

Try these in your `server{}`:

```
location ~ ^/mangas/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ {
   return 403; 
} 
location ~ ^/mangas/([^/]+)/$ { 
   return 403; 
} 
location ~ ^/mangas(/?)$ { 
   return 403; 
}

location / { 
   rewrite ^/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2&page=$3 break; 
   rewrite ^/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ /index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2 break; 
   rewrite ^/([^/.]+)(/?)$ /index.php?manga=$1 break; 
}
```

Comment: Still not work :(

When I try to access my website, look like download something "Application Stream". Anyone help me with other references?

Comment: @FikriOnline
What application server do you use for PHP? php-fpm? How did you configure nginx to interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

O certo seria:

```
location ~ ^/mangas/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ {
   return 403;
}

location ~ ^/mangas/([^/]+)/$ {
   return 403;
}
location ~ ^/mangas(/?)$ {
   return 403;
}
location / {
   rewrite ^/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2&page=$3 last;
   rewrite ^/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ /index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2 last;
   rewrite ^/([^/.]+)(/?)$ /index.php?manga=$1 last;
}
```

Não sei porquê, mas, alterando de break para last funciona.

Comment: Would you mind translating to English (if possible). Not being nasty or anything - but this site is an english language site to get the broadest coverage. Sticking it through google translate would do as a starter.